# Unwrapping Optional Type Any from Dictionary

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary, forced-unwrapping

I have previously asked a question similar to this however the answer doesn't seem to work.

I have a dictionary called Settings:

var settings = String: Any

This is filled by reading a text file - All works fine

when i run `println(settings)` it returns the filled dictionary as it should.

**[monsterRate: 1.0, monsterMinSpeed: 10.0, weaponPickupRate: 10.0, weaponPickupAmount: 50.0, goldPerMonster: 10.0, totalMonsters: 10.0, LevelNum: 1.0, monsterMaxSpeed: 15.0]**

If i run `println(settings["monsterMinSpeed"])` it returns **Optional("10.0")**

However when I try and set my variables to the values that the dictionary holds, it doesn't work:

```
    monsterMinSpeed = (settings["monsterMinSpeed"] as? Double) ?? 0.0
    monsterMaxSpeed = (settings["monsterMaxSpeed"] as? Double) ?? 0.0
    monsterRate = (settings["monsterRate"] as? Double) ?? 0.0
    weaponPickupAmount = (settings["weaponPickupAmount"] as? Double) ?? 0.0
    weaponPickupKills = (settings["weaponPickupKills"] as? Double) ?? 0.0
    goldPerMonster = (settings["goldPerMonster"] as? Double) ?? 0.0
```

Even though there are values in the dictionary, it always uses 0.0 as though the keys I am providing don't exist - returning the nil and therefore setting the variable to 0.0

Could someone please help?

Comment: Could it be because you can't cast objects to primitives? Try using `.doubleValue()` instead of `as? Double`.

Comment: Hi Ian, unsure as to what you are suggesting. Please could you explain further?

Comment: `var settings = String: Any` Why? It is almost _never_ necessary to use Any; AnyObject is better if you do it. And _your_ values are all Double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are coming in as strings, not numbers - try something like:

```
monsterMinSpeed = (settings["monsterMinSpeed"] as? NSString)?.doubleValue ?? 0.0
```

Comment: when using `monsterMinSpeed = (settings["monsterMinSpeed"] as? NSString)?.doubleValue` it gives me an error 

Value of optional type 'Double?' not unwrapped. Did you mean to use '!' or '?'.

However when it throws an error when using '!' and also when using neither

Comment: Updated - you'll still want the `??` operator.

Comment: If you are actually creating the dictionary, and it seems that you are,  I'd suggest using a [string:double] , unless you really plan on having values other than doubles.